# Extract entire url content using Regex

Tags: php, regex

Okay, I am using (PHP) file_get_contents to read some websites, these sites have only one link for facebook... after I get the entire site I will like to find the complete Url for facebook

So in some part there will be:

```
<a href="http://facebook.com/username" >
```

I wanna get http://facebook.com/username, I mean from the first (") to the last ("). Username is variable... could be username.somethingelse and I could have some attributes before or after "href".

Just in case i am  not being very clear:

```
<a href="http://facebook.com/username" >  //I want http://facebook.com/username
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/username" >  //I want http://www.facebook.com/username
<a class="value" href="http://facebook.com/username. some" attr="value" >  //I want http://facebook.com/username. some
```

or all example above, could be with singles quotes

```
<a href='http://facebook.com/username' > //I want http://facebook.com/username
```

Thanks to all

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use regex on HTML. It's a shotgun that'll blow off your leg at some point. Use DOM instead:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML(...);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);

$a_tags = $xp->query("//a");
foreach($a_tags as $a) {
   echo $a->getAttribute('href');
}
```

Comment: I wanted to provide a good resources explaining why you shouldn't use Regexp for the OP read. But I couldn't find the one I was thinking of. Any chance you have a good resource, Marc?

Comment: This is the canonical answer when html+regex comes up on this site: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: Well the true is that I am using DOM, to get part of the document where I know the link of facebook will be, but in that part I will get bewtween 1 to 6 links, how do I get just the one that have facebook

Comment: @richard: `$xp->query("//a[contains(@href,'facebook')]");`

Comment: @Marc it gave me this <a href="http://facebook.com/username. something" target="_blank">... but I want just http://facebook.com/username.something

Comment: You still need the `$a->getAttribute()` portion to extract JUST the `<a>`'s href attribute.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) for this very purpose rather than using regex. Here is a quick code sample for your case:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($content);

// To hold all your links...
$links = array();

$hrefTags = $dom->getElementsByTagName("a");
    foreach ($hrefTags as $hrefTag)
       $links[] = $hrefTag->getAttribute("href");

print_r($links); // dump all links
```